# SQL: Find rows where Column contains all of the given words

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some column EntityName, and I want to have users to be able to search names by entering words separated by space. The space is implicitly considered as an 'AND' operator, meaning that the returned rows must have all of the words specified, and not necessarily in the given order.

For example, if we have rows like these:

1. abba nina pretty balerina
2. acdc you shook me all night long
3. sth you are me
4. dream theater it's all about you

when the user enters: `me you`, or `you me` (the results must be equivalent), the result has rows 2 and 3.

I know I can go like:

```
WHERE Col1 LIKE '%' + word1 + '%'
  AND Col1 LIKE '%' + word2 + '%'
```

but I wanted to know if there's some more optimal solution.

The `CONTAINS` would require a full text index, which (for various reasons) is not an option.

Maybe Sql2008 has some built-in, semi-hidden solution for these cases?

Comment: I'm just curious to know the reasons why the full text index solution is off the table. That's certainly the way I'd want to go here.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply - it's not working for us because it doesn't support searches like the one I used as an example in question ('%term%' - the search that's not limited to separated words, but even words that only contain the term in it). And, furthermore, the SqlServer is on a clustered machine with shared network drives, and any additional instalations are frozen (and we need to install full-text search, because admins didn't include it when installing) - they assure us it's a hell to do additional instalations to nodes... so that's why it's off the table...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is to write a [`CLR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function that does the `LIKE` comparisons. This should be many times faster.

**Update:** Now that I think about it, it makes sense CLR would not help. Two other ideas:

1 - Try indexing Col1 and do this:

```
WHERE (Col1 LIKE word1 + '%' or Col1 LIKE '%' + word1 + '%')
  AND (Col1 LIKE word2 + '%' or Col1 LIKE '%' + word2 + '%')
```

Depending on the most common searches (starts with vs. substring), this may offer an improvement.

2 - Add your own full text indexing table where each word is a row in the table. Then you can index properly.

Comment: Even though I was against it at first, it seems that's the best solution so far...

Comment: After I've tried it, I want to add an update to this - it's just incredibly slow... if the 'like' method finishes in 10 seconds, this CLR function needs ...well I don't know - I just stopped it after 20 mins... so this solution is shelved as well...

Comment: the 1. doesn't cover the cases where the rows don't start with the search word (but it is faster because it can use index in that case). The 2. is ok, and we we're already thinking about it. Thanks for the updates!

Comment: @veljkoz: That is incorrect, #1 does cover substring matches, see the `OR` clause.

Answer (score 3):

## Function

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit] ( @sep CHAR(1), @str VARCHAR(512) )
 RETURNS TABLE AS
 RETURN (
           WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
           SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @str)
           UNION ALL
           SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @str, stop + 1)
           FROM Pieces
           WHERE stop > 0
      )

      SELECT
           pn AS Id,
           SUBSTRING(@str, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop - start ELSE 512 END) AS Data
      FROM
           Pieces
 )
```

## Query

```
 DECLARE @FilterTable TABLE (Data VARCHAR(512))

 INSERT INTO @FilterTable (Data)
 SELECT DISTINCT S.Data
 FROM fnSplit(' ', 'word1 word2 word3') S -- Contains words

 SELECT DISTINCT
      T.*
 FROM
      MyTable T
      INNER JOIN @FilterTable F1 ON T.Col1 LIKE '%' + F1.Data + '%'
      LEFT JOIN @FilterTable F2 ON T.Col1 NOT LIKE '%' + F2.Data + '%'
 WHERE
      F2.Data IS NULL
```

Source: [SQL SELECT WHERE field contains words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290857/sql-select-where-field-contains-words/27710530#27710530)

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You're going to end up with a full table scan anyway.

The collation can make a big difference apparently. Kalen Delaney in the book "[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Internals](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-SQL-Server-2008-Internals/dp/0735626243)" says:

> Collation can make a huge difference
>   when SQL Server has to look at almost
>   all characters in the strings. For
>   instance, look at the following:
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE longcol LIKE '%abc%'
> ```
>
> This may execute 10 times faster or more with a binary collation than a nonbinary Windows collation. And with `varchar` data, this executes up to seven or eight times faster with a SQL collation than with a Windows collation.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH Tokens AS(SELECT 'you' AS Token UNION ALL SELECT 'me')
SELECT ...
FROM YourTable AS t
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tokens WHERE y.Col1 LIKE '%'+Tokens.Token+'%') 
 = 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tokens) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should ideally be done with the help of Full text search as mentioned above.
BUT,
If you don't have full text configured for your DB, here is a performance intensive solution for doing a prioritized string search.

```
-- table to search in
drop table if exists dbo.myTable;
go
CREATE TABLE dbo.myTable
    (
    myTableId int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    code varchar(200) NOT NULL, 
    description varchar(200) NOT NULL -- this column contains the values we are going to search in 
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- function to split space separated search string into individual words
drop function if exists [dbo].[fnSplit];
go
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit] (@StringInput nvarchar(max),
@Delimiter nvarchar(1))
RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE (
  id nvarchar(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @String nvarchar(100);

  WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0
  BEGIN
    SET @String = LEFT(@StringInput, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringInput) - 1, -1),
    LEN(@StringInput)));
    SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX
    (
    @Delimiter, @StringInput
    ),
    0
    ), LEN
    (
    @StringInput)
    )
    + 1, LEN(@StringInput));

    INSERT INTO @OutputTable (id)
      VALUES (@String);
  END;

  RETURN;
END;
GO

-- this is the search script which can be optionally converted to a stored procedure /function


declare @search varchar(max) = 'infection upper acute genito'; -- enter your search string here
-- the searched string above should give rows containing the following
-- infection in upper side with acute genitointestinal tract
-- acute infection in upper teeth
-- acute genitointestinal pain

if (len(trim(@search)) = 0) -- if search string is empty, just return records ordered alphabetically
begin
 select 1 as Priority ,myTableid, code, Description from myTable order by Description 
 return;
end

declare @splitTable Table(
wordRank int Identity(1,1), -- individual words are assinged priority order (in order of occurence/position)
word varchar(200)
)
declare @nonWordTable Table( -- table to trim out auxiliary verbs, prepositions etc. from the search
id varchar(200)
)

insert into @nonWordTable values
('of'),
('with'),
('at'),
('in'),
('for'),
('on'),
('by'),
('like'),
('up'),
('off'),
('near'),
('is'),
('are'),
(','),
(':'),
(';')

insert into @splitTable
select id from dbo.fnSplit(@search,' '); -- this function gives you a table with rows containing all the space separated words of the search like in this e.g., the output will be -
--  id
-------------
-- infection
-- upper
-- acute
-- genito

delete s from @splitTable s join @nonWordTable n  on s.word = n.id; -- trimming out non-words here
declare @countOfSearchStrings int = (select count(word) from @splitTable);  -- count of space separated words for search
declare @highestPriority int = POWER(@countOfSearchStrings,3);

with plainMatches as
(
select myTableid, @highestPriority as Priority from myTable where Description like @search  -- exact matches have highest priority
union                                      
select myTableid, @highestPriority-1 as Priority from myTable where Description like  @search + '%'  -- then with something at the end
union                                      
select myTableid, @highestPriority-2 as Priority from myTable where Description like '%' + @search -- then with something at the beginning
union                                      
select myTableid, @highestPriority-3 as Priority from myTable where Description like '%' + @search + '%' -- then if the word falls somewhere in between
),
splitWordMatches as( -- give each searched word a rank based on its position in the searched string
                     -- and calculate its char index in the field to search
select myTable.myTableid, (@countOfSearchStrings - s.wordRank) as Priority, s.word,
wordIndex = CHARINDEX(s.word, myTable.Description)  from myTable join @splitTable s on myTable.Description like '%'+ s.word + '%'
-- and not exists(select myTableid from plainMatches p where p.myTableId = myTable.myTableId) -- need not look into myTables that have already been found in plainmatches as they are highest ranked
                                                                              -- this one takes a long time though, so commenting it, will have no impact on the result
),
matchingRowsWithAllWords as (
 select myTableid, count(myTableid) as myTableCount from splitWordMatches group by(myTableid) having count(myTableid) = @countOfSearchStrings
)
, -- trim off the CTE here if you don't care about the ordering of words to be considered for priority
wordIndexRatings as( -- reverse the char indexes retrived above so that words occuring earlier have higher weightage
                     -- and then normalize them to sequential values
select s.myTableid, Priority, word, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by s.myTableid order by wordindex desc) as comparativeWordIndex 
from splitWordMatches s join matchingRowsWithAllWords m on s.myTableId = m.myTableId
)
,
wordIndexSequenceRatings as ( -- need to do this to ensure that if the same set of words from search string is found in two rows,
                              -- their sequence in the field value is taken into account for higher priority
    select w.myTableid, w.word, (w.Priority + w.comparativeWordIndex + coalesce(sequncedPriority ,0)) as Priority
    from wordIndexRatings w left join 
    (
     select w1.myTableid, w1.priority, w1.word, w1.comparativeWordIndex, count(w1.myTableid) as sequncedPriority
     from wordIndexRatings w1 join wordIndexRatings w2 on w1.myTableId = w2.myTableId and w1.Priority > w2.Priority and w1.comparativeWordIndex>w2.comparativeWordIndex
     group by w1.myTableid, w1.priority,w1.word, w1.comparativeWordIndex
    ) 
    sequencedPriority on w.myTableId = sequencedPriority.myTableId and w.Priority = sequencedPriority.Priority
),
prioritizedSplitWordMatches as ( -- this calculates the cumulative priority for a field value
select  w1.myTableId, sum(w1.Priority) as OverallPriority from wordIndexSequenceRatings w1 join wordIndexSequenceRatings w2 on w1.myTableId =  w2.myTableId 
where w1.word <> w2.word group by w1.myTableid 
),
completeSet as (
select myTableid, priority from plainMatches -- get plain matches which should be highest ranked
union
select myTableid, OverallPriority as priority from prioritizedSplitWordMatches -- get ranked split word matches (which are ordered based on word rank in search string and sequence)
),
maximizedCompleteSet as( -- set the priority of a field value = maximum priority for that field value
select myTableid, max(priority) as Priority  from completeSet group by myTableId
)
select priority, myTable.myTableid , code, Description from maximizedCompleteSet m join myTable  on m.myTableId = myTable.myTableId 
order by Priority desc, Description -- order by priority desc to get highest rated items on top
--offset 0 rows fetch next 50 rows only -- optional paging
```