# Is there an advanced like function where i can get results even if one word matches

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function

hello I am trying to achieve something like this
should give results if

where 'Robert Doug' like '%Robert'

or

where 'Robert Doug' like '%Doug Robert'

if users enters first name or last name and if it matches in that whole string it should return the record.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: for the first instance `LIKE %Robert%`, for the second `LIKE '%Doug%' AND LIKE '%Robert%'`

Comment: Thank you it was example but i need something dynamic

Comment: for example Field like 'user prompt'

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290857/sql-select-where-field-contains-words

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT * FROM [YOUR TABLE_NAME] WHERE [COLUMN_NAME] LIKE ('%'+[USER PROMPT]+'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this..

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%Robert%',NAME_COLUMN)
FROM [YOUR TABLE_NAME]
```

Or..

```
SELECT NAME_COLUMN
FROM [YOUR TABLE_NAME]
WHERE PATINDEX('%Robert%',NAME_COLUMN)<>'0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all i tried something like this

WHERE
( d_searchJobTitle.term like  '%'+case when CHARINDEX(' ','implementation analyst')  >0 then SUBSTRING('implementation analyst',1,CHARINDEX(' ','implementation analyst')) else 'implementation analyst' end+'%'
and
d_searchJobTitle.term like  '%'+ case when CHARINDEX(' ','implementation analyst')  >0 then SUBSTRING('implementation analyst',CHARINDEX(' ','implementation analyst'),len('implementation analyst')) 
  else 'implementation analyst'  end

+'%'  )