# MySQL SELECT WHERE all set items are in another set

Tags: mysql, select

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
id | set_of_numbers
-------------------------
1  | "41,52,64,238,246"
2  | "41,52,64"
3  | "41,52,64,238,245,246,248,323,418"
4  | "89,52,64"    
5  | "31,52,64,128,246"
6  | "41,52,64"
7  | "41,52,64,238,245,248,323,418"
8  | "67,53,64"
```

Now I have a query set like `(64,246)` and I want to list all items that have ALL numbers in the query set. So the result will be `(1,3,5)`.

I'm using MySQL Procedure where the input is `(64,246)` so I don't have the numbers separated.

Comment: It's almost ever a bad idea to store comma separated lists in columns. That said, it should be easy to split in your procedure the input to a list of numbers and use FIND_IN_SET to find those in your second column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE 
(set_of_numbers LIKE '%64,' 
 OR set_of_numbers LIKE '%,64,%' 
 OR set_of_numbers LIKE ',64%' )
AND 
(set_of_numbers LIKE '%246,'
 OR set_of_numbers LIKE '%,246,%'
 OR set_of_numbers LIKE ',246%')
```

Here's a link to a similar [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290857/sql-select-where-field-contains-words), and here's a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) to w3school's explanation on the LIKE operator for your reference :)

Comment: It will give records for numbers like 644,464 and so on

Comment: The problem is I don't have the numbers separated. I'm using a Procedure where the input is (64,246).

Comment: Fixed the script based on M Khalid Junaid's comment :)