# Auto completion with multiple unordored words

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I'm using [this script](http://www.2my4edge.com/2013/08/autocomplete-search-using-php-mysql-and.html) and I want to modify/update it to work in this way:

In my database I have for example: `hello world, my name is John`. When I search `Hello World` or `orld, m` or `name i` I want to find the item, but if I search `world hello` or `name John` it doesn't work. So, I'm looking for the way to make it work. Could someone help me ?

Many Thanks

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".search").keyup(function() { 
            var searchid = $(this).val();
            var dataString = 'search=' + searchid;
            if (searchid != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "search.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) {
                        $("#result").html(html).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;    
        });

        jQuery("#result").live("click", function(e){ 
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
            var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
            $('#searchid').val(decoded);
        });

        jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
                jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
            }
        });

        $('#searchid').click(function(){
            jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    body { 
        font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .content {
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #searchid { 
        width: 90%;
        border: solid 1px #000;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    #result {
        position: absolute;
        width: 70%;
        padding: 15px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: -1px;
        border-top: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px #CCC solid;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
    }
    .show {
        padding: 4px; 
        border-bottom: 1px #999 dashed;
        font-size: 12px; 
        height: 58px;
    }
    .show:hover {
        background: #4c66a4;
        color: #FFF;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

Search.php

```
<?php
    include('admin/db.php');
    if($_POST)
    {
        $q = $_POST['search'];
        $sql_res = mysql_query("select id, name, email, infos from autocomplete where name like '%$q%' or email like '%$q%' or infos like '%$q%' order by id LIMIT 100");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
        {
            $username = $row['name'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            $infos = $row['infos'];
            $b_username = '<strong><font style="color: black; background-color: #ffff42">'.$q.'</strong></font>';
            $b_email = '<strong><font style="color: black; background-color: #ffff42">'.$q.'</strong></font>';
            $b_infos = '<strong><font style="color: black; background-color: #ffff42">'.$q.'</strong></font>';
            $final_username = str_ireplace($q, $b_username, $username);
            $final_email = str_ireplace($q, $b_email, $email);
            $final_infos = str_ireplace($q, $b_infos, $infos);
        ?>
        <div class="show" align="left">
            <span class="name">
                <?php echo $final_username; ?>
            </span>&nbsp;<br/>
            <?php echo $final_email; ?>
            </span>&nbsp;<br/>
            <?php echo $final_infos; ?><br/>
        </div>
    <?php }
} ?>
```

Comment: The MySQL `LIKE` clause isn't smart enough to find records with words in a different order. Your best bet would be to split the search query into words and cycle through each word adding a point to each search result that comes up, then ordering the results by how many points it has.

Comment: You should also update the script to use MySQli or PDO. Depending on your db you're using you could try using  MATCH() ... AGAINST.

Answer (score 1):

you should take look to levenshtein function.

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.levenshtein.php

Try to make your own algo, it will increase your skill.

Answer (score 0):

i'm french too ! :D

Here you search a query like "name is" you're request search in Name, email, and info column all results who contain exactly "name is".

If you want to search word by word you need to use a boucle for each word in you're search query store in a tempory table the results and return all the result who contain each word.

There's maybe an other solution look here : [SQL SELECT WHERE field contains words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290857/sql-select-where-field-contains-words)