# Android Database SELECT FROM WHERE

Tags: android, sqlite

My data is " 1 1/2 Pounds boneless, skinless chicken breasts"

I have this code to search a keyword inside a certain field.

```
String sQuery= "SELECT _id," + RECIPE_NAME + " FROM " + TBL_NAME +" WHERE ING_1 %" + "'Chicken'" +"%";Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sQuery,null);
```

I am just searching for a certain word in my data. I dont know how should it be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL SELECT WHERE field contains words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290857/sql-select-where-field-contains-words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the like keyword. Without that the wildcards are useless :)

```
String sQuery= "SELECT _id," + RECIPE_NAME + " FROM " + TBL_NAME +" WHERE ING_1 like %" + "'Chicken'" +"%";Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sQuery,null);
```