# How to run a SQL query that searches for a part of the keyword in the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

The keyword is automatically passed into the query. Suppose the keyword passed is 'Database Manager', now I want to display all results containing 'database'. i.e, it should query the first word of the two-letter keyword. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks. This is my query right now:

```
$jobQuerySqlStmt .= "
Select * 
  from job 
 WHERE specialization LIKE '$" . $this->paraValues[$std1->JOB_TABLE_SPECIALIZATION] . "%'";
```

I want the first word of `$this->paraValues[$std1->JOB_TABLE_SPECIALIZATION]` to be searched for, only.

Comment: You would need to split the string (if you just want the first word only).  You should be able to do that via SQL or PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL SELECT WHERE field contains words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290857/sql-select-where-field-contains-words)

Answer (score 0):

you might require to add % before and after the $ as below:

```
$jobQuerySqlStmt .= "
Select * 
 from job 
  WHERE specialization LIKE '%$%" . $this->paraValues[$std1->JOB_TABLE_SPECIALIZATION] . "%'";
```

Comment: That still searches for the exact keyword passed. I want to search for a part of the keyword that is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Sub 'Database Manager' with your variable that has the two word search term:

```
DECLARE @FirstWord NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @FirstWord = SUBSTRING('Database Manager', 1, CHARINDEX(' ', 'Database 
Manager'))
```

Then you query will be like this:

```
Select * 
  from job 
 WHERE specialization LIKE @FirstWord + '%'
```