# SQL SELECT only field where it contains words

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm interested in doing something [like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290857/sql-select-where-field-contains-words), where I only get the result, if the column actually contains all the words given to it.

For example, if I have two columns, one being a timestamp, the other being the weather, I want to get only the timestamps where the weather was `cloudy`, `rainy`, `snowy`, and not if it was only `cloudy`, `rainy`. An example of the above would be sort of like:

```
SELECT distinct timestamp FROM mytable
WHERE Weather LIKE 'snowy'
   OR Weather LIKE 'cloudy'
   OR Weather LIKE 'rainy'
```

Which would return something like:

```
2017-09-22 snowy
2017-09-22 snowy
2017-09-22 cloudy
2017-09-22 rainy
2017-09-22 cloudy
```

But not any results `from 2017-09-21`, because it might only have been `snowy` and `rainy` that day etc.

The example query I did above would return all timestamps, as long as the weather matched the criteria.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`.  I would recommend:

```
SELECT timestamp
FROM mytable
WHERE Weather IN ('snowy', 'cloudy', 'rainy')
GROUP BY timestamp
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Weather) = 3;  -- get all of them
```

If you have no duplicates for `timestamp`/`Weather` in the table, then use `COUNT(*) = 3` instead of `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use like bellow ,

SELECT timestamp
  FROM mytable
  WHERE Weather IN ('snowy', 'cloudy', 'rainy')

Output :
example

1

2

3

Dummy table

1   snowy

2   cloudy

3   rainy

4   aaaa

5   bbbb

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.