# SQL first query

Tags: sql

I am just learning SQL and I was trying to link Inner Join three tables together but for some reason I cant search for the word I am looking for.

```
SELECT
  PopTartID,
  StoreName,
  PopTartFlavor
FROM tKrogerStore_PopTart
INNER JOIN tKrogerStore
  ON tKrogerStore_PopTart.KrogerStoreID
  = tKrogerStore.KrogerStoreID
INNER JOIN tPopTartFlavor
  ON tPopTartFlavor.PopTartFlavor
  = tKrogerStore_PopTart.PopTartID
WHERE PopTartFlavor = Bacon
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL SELECT WHERE field contains words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290857/sql-select-where-field-contains-words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching for the word `Bacon`, then you need to use single quotes to make it as string literal

```
SELECT PopTartID,
       StoreName,
       PopTartFlavor
FROM   tKrogerStore_PopTart
       INNER JOIN tKrogerStore
               ON tKrogerStore_PopTart.KrogerStoreID = tKrogerStore.KrogerStoreID
       INNER JOIN tPopTartFlavor
               ON tPopTartFlavor.PopTartFlavor = tKrogerStore_PopTart.PopTartID
WHERE  PopTartFlavor = 'Bacon' --here
```

Comment: Thank you ! that was my problem.