# Count the number of occurrence of 7 and 0 from the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a data like below format, now I want to count the occurrences of '7' and '0', like how many time it's showed up in the table from 'vi' column ??

```
ci vi 
1  7  
2  0  
3  0  
4  7  
5  7
6  10
7  15
8  0
9  16
10 7
11 0
12 35
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like a straight forward `WHERE ... GROUP BY` query. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL SELECT WHERE field contains words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290857/sql-select-where-field-contains-words)

Comment: Hint:  `COUNT()`, `WHERE`.

Comment: What is the data type of `vi` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  ;WITH CTE(ci ,vi )
AS
(
SELECT 1  ,7   UNION ALL
SELECT 2  ,0   UNION ALL
SELECT 3  ,0   UNION ALL
SELECT 4  ,7   UNION ALL
SELECT 5  ,7   UNION ALL
SELECT 6  ,10  UNION ALL
SELECT 7  ,15  UNION ALL
SELECT 8  ,0   UNION ALL
SELECT 9  ,16  UNION ALL
SELECT 10 ,7   UNION ALL
SELECT 11 ,0   UNION ALL
SELECT 12 ,35 
)
SELECT vi,COUNT(vi) Occurence
FROM CTE
WHERE vi IN (7,0) -- Specific values count Required use this where condition else remove
GROUP BY vi
```

Result

```
vi  Occurence
--------------
0      4
7      4
```

Comment: Happy to help bro :)

Answer (score 2):

MS SQL 
Can be achieved by GROUP BY

```
select vi, count(1) [COUNT] from @table1
group by vi
having vi in (7,0)
```

[DEMO](https://rextester.com/MCU16725)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `sum` and `case-when` like:

```
select
     sum(case when vi = 7 then 1 else 0 end) as [7Count],
     sum(case when vi = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as [0Count]
from table
```