# How can I retrieve from MySQL database using JPA/Hibernate a list of products whose description or name contains some given words?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Supposing I have a Product table in my database with the following columns: id, name, and description. I want to write a query in ProductRepository which extends JPA Repository, that allows me to retrieve a list of products whose description or name contain some given words. These words come from a string array.

I managed to implement this query for only a single word given and it works, but can't figure out how to do it for multiple words.

I appreciate any advice you could give me!

ProductRepository:

@Query(value="SELECT * FROM product WHERE description LIKE CONCAT('%',:word,'%') OR name LIKE CONCAT('%',:word,'%')", nativeQuery =true)

Set findProductsByGivenWords(String [] words);
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD5HG.png)

Comment: You would like all the words contains in description or name?

Comment: Exactly Pavel! The result must contain all the words given

Comment: What is DBMS you are using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: You can write native query to DB using the [next examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290857/sql-select-where-field-contains-words). The complicity of the query depends from DBMS, for example, Oracle has a build-in command CONTAINS. Try to find something for your case.