# What does '%***%' mean?

Tags: sql

I see a SQL code like this
`select * from table where id not like '%***%'`
What is this code trying to exclude?

Comment: in SQL `%` is a wildcard (zero or more characters). You are selecting any id without `***` in it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL SELECT WHERE field contains words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290857/sql-select-where-field-contains-words)

Answer (score 0):

The `%` is a wildcard.  The `***` doesn't mean anything special.  So `%***%` means "any string that has `***` somewhere in it."

If it was `%***` it would be "any string that ended with `***`" and if it was `***%` it would be "any string that starts with `***`".

Answer (score 0):

Basically :

```sql
LIKE 'e%' -- results that start with “e”
LIKE '%e' -- results that ends with “e”
```

But here, with your example :

```sql
select * from table where id not like '%exemple%'
```

Here, you are going to search every id in your table except "exemple" keyword