# SQL SELECT where multiple columns contain any part of submitted string

Tags: mysql, select

Expanding on this thread which is not exactly what i'm after - [SQL SELECT WHERE field contains words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290857/sql-select-where-field-contains-words)

I have a Name field for someone to enter full name (first name and last name) but MySQL database has the data split in to 2 columns, usrFirstName and usrLastName.

I am looking to select either any member where usrFirstName and usrLastName is identical to the string, or in the event that only a last name may be entered, all members where usrLastName is identical to the string.

I have tried "SELECT * from users WHERE usrFirstName LIKE ? or usrLastName LIKE ?" (where ? is the submitted string) but this isn't working because it is looking for a full name in either column.

Would appreciate any assistance, many thanks.

Comment: Is this a MySQL problem or an AJAX problem? Please share more details, like the code involved

Comment: Perhaps `SELECT * from users WHERE TRIM(CONCAT_WS(' ', usrFirstName, usrLastName)) = ?`

Comment: when you bind the variable put the wildcards at the beginning and end of the string you pass (% is the wildcard operator)

Comment: how is ajax related to this question?

Comment: If you're looking for identical matches, then use `=` rather than `LIKE`

Comment: Thanks Rob, that looks like it would work if the user entered a full name to search for, but in the instance that they may just search for a surname i.e. 'Smith' would it still return all rows that had 'Smith' in the concatenated string or is that where I should use LIKE instead of = so it is not identical?

Comment: @Adey have you tried what i am suggesting you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE TRIM(CONCAT_WS(' ', usrFirstName, usrLastName)) = ?
OR usrLastName = ?
```

(where `?` is the parameter you want to search with)

`CONCAT_WS` is used to join the first name and last name with a space.  If either of these is null (for example, a missing first name), they are skipped.

`TRIM` is used to remove any leading or trailing spaces in the data (which could occur if, for example, first name or last name is an empty string)

`=` is used (rather than `LIKE`) to ensure an identical match.  If instead you want to search for part of a full name or part of a last name, change `= ?` to `LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')`

Comment: Thanks Rob, that looks like it would work if the user entered a full name to search for, but in the instance that they may just search for a surname i.e. 'Smith' would it still return all rows that had 'Smith' in the concatenated string or is that where I should use LIKE instead of = so it is not identical?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood - I thought you meant that the first name could be blank in the database.  I have adapted the answer to also include rows where the last name is identical to the search string

Comment: Thank you, yes there will always be a first and last name in the database but the admin user searching may either search for a full name or a part name and be returned a list of users.